# How do I return the result of a stored procedure to a select statement that is being used to insert records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am writing a script to transform some data following a software update. I am introducing a new table and need to extract data from an existing table into this new table. I need to take an existing varchar(max) field from one table, create a parent child record based on it in another table and insert the identity of the new parent record in another table.

So it kinda want to look like this

```
INSERT INTO NEWTABLE (val1, val2, val3) 
SELECT 
    val1,
    val2,
    EXEC AStoredProc(val3) -- this obviosuly doesnt work
FROM EXISTINGTABLE

CREATE PROCEDURE AStoredProc
  @Value nvarchar(max),
  @NewID int OUTPUT

  DECLARE @ParentID int

  INSERT INTO AnotherTable ([Text], ParentNodeID)
  VALUES ('',NULL)

  SELECT @ParentID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

  INSERT INTO AnotherTable  ([Text], ParentNodeID)
  VALUES (@Value,@ParentID)

  SELECT @ParentID

END
```

In the above example val1 and val2 fields are just being migrated directly to the new table. val3 in the new table is an int and is being inserted from the result of AStoredProc which takes the varchar(max) val3 value of the Existing table creates a couple of records in another table and returns the new parent ID from them, which is then inserted as val3 in the new table.

Without worrying about the whys of the design, how can I essentially run some insert stuff in a Stored Proc and have the result returned directly to the outer Select statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two options I can think of are:

1. Use a `CURSOR`:

   ```sql
   DECLARE @val1 datatype1,
           @val2 datatype2,
           @val3 NVARCHAR(MAX),
           @ParentID INT;

   DECLARE migrate CURSOR LOCAL STATIC
   FOR  SELECT et.val1, et.val2, et.val3
        FROM   EXISTINGTABLE et
        WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
                      SELECT *
                      FROM   NEWTABLE nt
                      WHERE  nt.val1 = et.val1
                      AND    nt.val2 = et.val2
                          );

   BEGIN TRY

   OPEN migrate

   FETCH NEXT
   FROM  migrate
   INTO  @val1, @val2, @val3;

   WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> 0)
   BEGIN
     BEGIN TRAN;

     EXEC dbo.AStoredProc
              @Value = @val3,
              @NewID = @ParentID OUTPUT;

     INSERT INTO NEWTABLE (val1, val2, val3)
     VALUES (@val1, @val2, @ParentID);

     COMMIT;
   END;

   CLOSE migrate;
   DEALLOCATE migrate;

   END TRY
   BEGIN CATCH
     ROLLBACK TRAN;
     -- catch block stuff goes here
   END CATCH;
   ```
2. Create a "temporary" column in at least the first `AnotherTable` listed in the stored procedure in the example code (i.e. the table generating the `@ParentID` value) to hold an association for the newly created records. This would allow for doing set-based operations since the queries could then be done as separate steps. If there is already an IDENTITY value / easy to use PK in `EXISTINGTABLE` then just use that, else a new value can be created easily if the temporary column is `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` and just use `NEWID()`. But assuming happy path for the moment (i.e. `EXISTINGTABLE` has `INT` PK), then it would be something like:

   ```sql
   -- set up temporary association column
   ALTER TABLE dbo.AnotherTable
     ADD [TempAssociationID] INT NOT NULL;

   BEGIN TRY

   BEGIN TRAN;

   -- populate initial "parent" records
   INSERT INTO dbo.AnotherTable ([Text], [TempAssociationID])
     SELECT '', et.PK_column
     FROM   dbo.EXISTINGTABLE et;

   -- populate "child" records
   INSERT INTO dbo.AnotherTable ([Text], [TempAssociationID], ParentNodeID)
     SELECT et.val3, et.PK_column, anthr.ID_column AS [ParentNodeID]
     FROM   dbo.EXISTINGTABLE et
     INNER JOIN  dbo.AnotherTable anthr
             ON  anthr.[TempAssociationID] = et.PK_column
            AND  anthr.[ParentNodeID] IS NULL;

   -- combine existing and secondary tables for "new" table
   INSERT INTO dbo.NEWTABLE (val1, val2, val3)
     SELECT  et.val1, et.val2, anthr.ID_column AS [val3]
     FROM    dbo.EXISTINGTABLE et
     INNER JOIN  dbo.AnotherTable anthr
             ON  anthr.[TempAssociationID] = et.PK_column
            AND  anthr.[ParentNodeID] IS NULL;

   COMMIT TRAN;

   END TRY
   BEGIN CATCH
     ROLLBACK TRAN;
     -- other catch block stuffs
   END CATCH;

   ALTER TABLE dbo.AnotherTable
     DROP COLUMN [TempAssociationID];
   ```

Comment: Yeah, I kind of figured they would be my options. Think I'm going to go for the cursor approach. Was sort of hoping it could be done in one easily rollbackable transaction

Comment: @StewartAlan It can be...let me finish option 2 ;-).

Comment: @StewartAlan please see the competed option #2 :)